# [?2004l characters when login through ssh in debian

Tags: debian, environment-variables, prompt

I have recently modified the $PS1 environment variable in /etc/bash.bashrc in Debian. To make those changes in my current session, I thought that I could restart bash.bashrc with:

```
. /etc/bash.bashrc
```

as you would usually do to restart /home/%u/bash.rc
But when I did that, my prompt appeared to be loading something, so I did "ctrl+C", and I could only see ?2004l characters printed. I tried to restart the ssh connection and login again, and even restarting the machine, but none of this worked.

[image: The two last lines are the output]

As you can see in the screenshot, I can login but this is the only thing I see, and I can't type commands.

Comment: Try and get a proper terminal emulator, one that supports mouse positioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you can log in via SSH, you can (almost certainly) use scp to download, fix, and upload your fixed .bashrc.

If you want to temporarily disable loading your ~/.bashrc when logging in, specify that you want to run `/bin/bash --norc` from ssh, i.e.,

```
ssh -t user@host /bin/bash --norc
```